# Reading and comparing contents of a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I am trying to implement a Search Function for my app.
The search needs to involve several files that are in the server side.

So, I thought about reading each file to check if the search term is contained in them.

Code:

```
function search()
{
    var term = document.getElementById("search-input").value; 
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("helpfiles");
    var fileList = fileInput.files;

    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(fileList[i]); 
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            var text = reader.result;
            alert(text) // test purpose only
            if(text.indexOf(term) !== -1) // PROBLEM HERE
                alert(fileList[i].name)

        }               
    }
}
```

Until the code line:

```
alert(text)
```

everything works well.

The problem happens in the if-statement that it simply does not work as expected.

Comment: What happens if you do this? if( text.indexOf(term) )    and   console.log( fileList[i] )

Comment: @25r43q `indexOf` returns `-1` if the search term was not found and `0` if it is at the beginning. So your if condition tests if `text` does not start with `term`.

Comment: thanks @t.niese, but the question was aimed to see what the output in fileList[i] is when the function breaks. Is the fileList an array, object, null? Thats why I want to see what happens. But thanks for the correction on the truthycheck :)

Comment: @25r43q fileList is an array of files. If I do what you told, I get [object File]